# Elantech Touchpad does not work under Windows 7, works under Windows 10 & Debian 8

Tags: windows-7, drivers, touchpad

I have an [ASUS ROG GL552VW laptop](https://www.asus.com/us/ROG-Republic-Of-Gamers/ROG-GL552VW/), which came preinstalled with Windows 10. For various reasons, I refuse to use Windows 10 (the only exception might be if I could get the same performance out of a Windows 7 VM, but I've tested it and the graphics performance is way too slow).

I have been using Windows 7 for over a year on this laptop and everything works correctly *except* for the touchpad. I recently explored other options such as Debian 8 and Windows 10, but neither of them natively support some of the programs I use on a regular basis and, as I stated above, I got abysmal graphics performance trying to run a Windows 7 VM.

The touchpad does work correctly under Windows 10 and Debian 8 (with the Linux 4.9 kernel; it does not work with the 3.16 kernel).

On Windows 7, I have an "Unknown device" with hardware ID "ACPI\ELAN1000", which is the touchpad, but my attempts to install drivers have failed. All driver downloads on the ASUS website either fail ("wrong Windows version" or "device not present") or install without an apparently matching driver.

Is it possible to somehow port the Windows 10 or Linux driver to Windows 7? I'm done holding my breath for this to work, but I figured I'd ask seeing as it's clearly a software issue and not a hardware one.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find a solution?